# Dell G5 5587 fingerprint reader

Tags: dell, ubuntu-drivers, fingerprint-reader

I have a problem with my fingerprint scanner, i installed fingerprint GUI and it shows "no devices found" my laptop is Dell G5 5587 and i'm using UBUNTU 16.04

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted, Ahmed ... Anyway, I'm experiencing the same thing, even though I've updated my G5 to 18.10. If anyone has a solution for that, it would be nice.

Comment: Any issues when updating to 18? @BriceP

Comment: @JordanMackie Sorry I didn't answer earlier, I didn't get any notification. For anyone interrested, the update didn't bring any new issue, but didn't fix that specific problem.